# Adreno 420 driver bug on Android 5.1

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es-2.0

Just wanted to share an experience I had to see if anyone came across such issue, if they found the cause and more importantly how they fixed it.

The problem is pretty simple: while debugging native code on a Nexus 6, which as the Adreno 420 GPU, eglSwapBuffer could crash under certain circumstances when using Android 5.1 (5.0 worked perfectly).
Since I could not repro it I am unable to tell you what went wrong. According to the documentation, elgSwapBuffer calls internally glFlush; and so if I call glFlush before calling eglSwapBuffer all of a sudden it works perfectly. 
My guess is that the driver does not flush properly thus crashing when swaping the buffers.

Any comments on this?

Cheers,
D

Comment: How can you say it works perfectly if you can't reproduce the problem anyway?

Comment: Check for the memory constrains while this crash happened and also post the crash logs here. If you think it is a rare issue then use tools like crashlytics, crash logs, etc.. which shall provide you the logs when app crashes through email or tool.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Right. I can reproduce in the flow of the app. But as you can expect, swapping buffers is a pretty common command. You could argue that I'm missing something which is causing the issue, this would be a valid point if more than one device/gpu was affected by this which is not the case. By perfectly I mean that stops crashing, as simple as this.

Comment: @Iqbal Haven't tried anything other that the monitor.bat that comes with the Android SDK (or NDK?). Sadly nothing very useful is logged there.

Comment: Oh OK. Henceforth please integrate one of the tools I mentioned, those will be very helpful to trace the logs.

Comment: This issue might be of interest.  I just contributed a Nexus 6 5.0 stack trace that indicated the same thing.  
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem and I can reproduce it. It happens obviously because it runs out of stack memory due to deep nested loops in the rendering process.

[Android Lollipop 5.1: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x9e985ff8 in tid 4093 (RenderThread) / when using lot of nine patch graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437756/android-lollipop-5-1-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0x9e985ff8-i)

I've already reported it to the google issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163100

Update: Meanwhile I found a way to work around this issue. It's definitely not a long time solution, but for the moment, it's just the best available to stop my apps from crashing.

I disabled GPU rendering for particular graphic layers. It slows the drawing down a bit, but not significant.

So the nightmare is over for now, but I still think, this issue must be fixed on the driver itself. It cannot be that something that worked perfect with 5.0.2 and below, immediately stops to work with 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some weird behavior on the N6 as well, and while I cannot rule out app bugs, it looks to me like the Adreno driver is to blame.

Specifically, in landscape mode, our GLSurfaceView only renders one half of it's content, but occasionally flickers all of it. And with certain scenes being rendered there is intermittent flickering. In a case of extra weirdness, I have seen one half of the screen completely freeze, stuck on app content, even after returning to the launcher via the home button. It appears kind of like it would if it used multi stream transport and one of the streams was getting lost.