# Custom Listview crashes while loading images only in Android lollipop and higher os versions

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I have an android application that works well for all OS versions below Lollipop(5.0) For Lollipop and higher versions however, it crashes with a

```
    01-01 17:05:41.406: A/libc(3486): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa001cc10 in tid 3523 (RenderThread)
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:5.0/LRX21M/buildbot12151835:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): Revision: '0'
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): ABI: 'x86'
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): pid: 2726, tid: 2768, name: RenderThread  >>> supernet.interactapp <<<
01-01 16:58:16.067: I/DEBUG(75): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xa001cb50
01-01 16:58:16.093: I/DEBUG(75):     eax a47ff980  ebx b6a9e4fc  ecx 00000002  edx a2816a3c
01-01 16:58:16.093: I/DEBUG(75):     esi a4811280  edi a001cb50
01-01 16:58:16.093: I/DEBUG(75):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 000000a7  xss 0000007b
01-01 16:58:16.093: I/DEBUG(75):     eip b6a6cd2d  ebp a48112a4  esp a2816a00  flags 00210287
01-01 16:58:16.093: I/DEBUG(75): backtrace:
01-01 16:58:16.094: I/DEBUG(75):     #00 pc 0007cd2d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #01 pc 00025fa6  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::Caches::clearGarbage()+38)
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #02 pc 00041646  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #03 pc 0002b94d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #04 pc 00080d89  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #05 pc 000854f6  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-01 16:58:16.095: I/DEBUG(75):     #06 pc 0008a129  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+153)
01-01 16:58:16.096: I/DEBUG(75):     #07 pc 000169de  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
01-01 16:58:16.096: I/DEBUG(75):     #08 pc 0006fe92  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
01-01 16:58:16.096: I/DEBUG(75):     #09 pc 000160fa  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
01-01 16:58:16.096: I/DEBUG(75):     #10 pc 00020b78  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
01-01 16:58:16.096: I/DEBUG(75):     #11 pc 0001bfd9  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
01-01 16:58:16.097: I/DEBUG(75):     #12 pc 00012bc6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
```

I have no idea what causes this other than my suspicion that I must have offended the ART in some way with my coding style??

I have no native code at all in my application, and my best effort is that I traced the crash to the method that loads contacts from the file system in an `AsyncTask`(called in the `onCreate` of the activity that is called when the application crashes.

1. When this code is used in an `AsyncTask`, it crashes
2. When this code is not used in an `AsyncTask`, it still crashes.
3. But when the code is absent, it does not crash.
4. Whenever it crashes, it crashes regardless of the method from which
   it is called; be it `onCreate`, `onResume` or other

I also do not believe that its a memory issue, because I am loading only 3 items onto the contacts list..each of the list's rows have images of sizes
 **`23Kb, 65Kb and 48Kb`** respectively. 
I have used this code to load by far more contacts on devices running KitKat and lower versions of android.

Here is the offending code(offending to ART, not Dalvik):

```
/**
 *  
 * Loads the contacts list
 */
public static void loadContactsList(final Runnable onComplete){

    final Context context = getApplicationContext();


    class Loader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Client>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();   
    }//end method onPreExecute.

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Client> doInBackground(String... params) {

            List<String>ids =  Client.loadClientIds(context);
            Utils.logErrorMessage("ids = "+ids);
            ArrayList<Client>main = new ArrayList<Client>();

            for(String id:ids){
                Client c = Client.loadClient(context,id,true);
            if(c!=null && !c.isOwner()){
                main.add(c);
            }

            }

            Utils.logErrorMessage("done loading clients: see = "+main.size()+" clients loaded");

        return main;    
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Client> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Utils.logErrorMessage("On ui thread, showing results! adapter = "+ContactsActivity.adapter);

            ContactsActivity.adapter.setClients(  result  );
                onComplete.run();

                Utils.logErrorMessage("Done rendering in onPostExecute!");
        }// end onPostExecute

    }// end inner class
     new Loader().execute();
    /*
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             new Loader().execute();    
         }
      });
            */



}
```

Whenever this method is called in any activity in my application, it crashes.

The code for the `loadClient` is:

```
/**
 * Loads an Interact friend on this device.
 * @param id the id of the Client to be loaded
 * @param loadProfileImage If true, the client's profile image is loaded 
 * in the process. For some applications, the image does not need to be
 * loaded so set it to false.
 */
public static Client loadClient(Context context,String id,boolean loadProfileImage){
File clientData = new File(Utils.CONTACTS_FOLDER.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+id+".txt");
if(!clientData.exists()){

    //Perhaps its an owner account, search for that too.
    clientData = new File(Utils.CONTACTS_FOLDER.getAbsolutePath()+"/_owner"+id+".txt"); 
    if(!clientData.exists()){ 
        return null;
    }

}

String clientsJSON = new TextFileReader(clientData).read();
Client client = parseJsonToClient(clientsJSON);

if(loadProfileImage && client!=null && client.getProfilePix() != null && !client.getProfilePix().isEmpty()){
        client.setData(ImageUtilities.loadIcon(client.getProfilePix()));
    }
return client;
}
```

Please any help would be worth it.

**EDIT**

Also when I turned off hardware acceleration in the manifest as @Tasos suggested, the log changed to:

```
01-01 19:27:13.906: A/libc(12495): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa001cc10 in tid 12505 (FinalizerDaemon)
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:5.0/LRX21M/buildbot12151835:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): Revision: '0'
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): ABI: 'x86'
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): pid: 12495, tid: 12505, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> supernet.interactapp <<<
01-01 19:27:14.010: I/DEBUG(75): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     eax ffffffff  ebx b571ebac  ecx 00000001  edx ffffffff
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     esi a001cc10  edi a001cc10
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000002f  xss 0000007b
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     eip b539c9fb  ebp 00000000  esp b39e7970  flags 00210286
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75): backtrace:
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     #00 pc 001019fb  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::freePixels()+43)
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     #01 pc 00101a6a  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::~SkBitmap()+26)
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     #02 pc 000dcee3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     #03 pc 0001cbfe  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
01-01 19:27:14.033: I/DEBUG(75):     #04 pc fffffffe  <unknown>
01-01 19:27:14.137: I/DEBUG(75): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
01-01 19:27:14.138: I/BootReceiver(456): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

Comment: might be a gpu issue as you rendering pics -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437756/android-lollipop-5-1-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0x9e985ff8-i

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I looked up the link and I have no nine-patch images on the activity I am trying to open. The above issue also happens in other activities in the application, even those where I have only one bitmap image of moderate size.

Comment: yeah i understand but it maybe a graphics driver issue. try that solution anyway rendering on the software layer, it wont hurt :)

Comment: Hmmmm, where should I apply it? on the listview or on its custom cells?

Comment: what kind of view you have, eg imageview etc

Comment: actually easiest way for now is turn off hardware acceleration for the whole app just as a test in your manifest file  (<application
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false">)

Comment: Each row of the listview has an imageview  and 2 textviews or so. And I have tried turning off hardware acceleration some days ago without success...I'll try it again now.

Comment: well here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html you find various ways to turn off HA

Comment: I just tried turning it off, but it didn't work.

Comment: hmm, balls.  not sure then. maybe its a thread issue like not running on the main thread

Comment: Actually when I turned off hardware acceleration, the error log changed a bit.. I now have SIGSEGV in (FinalizerDaemon) instead of (RenderThread). The error is no longer in /system/lib/libhwui.so but in /system/lib/libskia.so

Comment: yeah, looks like an os bug -- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58515

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99499/discussion-between-gbenroscience-and-tasos).

Comment: Actually, I have an intent-filter in a BroadcastReceiver defined in my manifest. Since, lollipop does not support implicit intents, do you think this could affect  it?

Comment: not sure, never used them but i just came across this -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGElAW224dE