# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x37acd7ac in tid 14358

Tags: android, gradle, fatal-error

I just run into s problem.When I changed my gradle version to 2.1.0(old version is 1.5.0),my code went wrong.And it's wierd there is no logcat,so I just don't know how to find the problem and the wrong part code. I have tryed to add  android:allowClearUserData="true" in my AndroidManifest .it turns out not working. when I change my gradle version to the old one,it goes well.I am a new coder,and I use Retrofit to do the network job.plz just help me.Oh and I open the OpenGL stack in the logcat,It will call glGetError() then it goes crush.

Comment: add p.s the proble only happen on my nexus6p,another device just go fine

Comment: nexus 6p means it ll has android marshmallow.. so might be some issue in the permission check.. you might need to add runtime permission in 6.0 and above. so check is there any runtime permission you need to add while starting the app.

Comment: all the permissions has been grant,And as change the gradle version will be  ok,so actually i don't think it's the permission proble  but still thank you.And do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have this problem too. We upgraded from Gradle 1.2.3 to 2.1.0 and we get the exact same crash when loading a specific activity. Upgrading to 2.0.0 works just fine. I suspect it's a bug in Gradle 2.1.0

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue can up please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760308/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0x7fa4c3813c-in-tid-21198-crashly

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I have no idea. If only upgrading AS, it should be not crashed, but for possible updated SDK or Build tool Env. If you back to 1.5, even no crash when using same platform sdk, support library sdk?
After upgrading 2.1.0, When was crash happened? launching app, or opening some Activity? If later, you should limit your code to some extension, then searching from Google.

From crash info, it should be related with JNI. if you use JNI,your app has a library path in the app installed directory to list all support ABI .so. You could found the differ btw woking machine and abnormal one. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437756/android-lollipop-5-1-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0x9e985ff8-i?rq=1) stackOverflow, you can try too.

Comment: thank u. the problem is not the same one as the 9.patch. But today I update the as to 2.2preview. the problem was solved.the project don't crush any more.